# Apple payments down returning 'Payment not current'? Anyone else having this issue?

Tags: ios, app-store, payment

Is anyone having problems with apple payments right now? Have lots of errors in our logs for 'Payment not current' blocking users. To clarify, users who are paying a monthly subscription through apple are getting an error back from Apple.

More reports summarised from [Apple's developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/133367):

- Users open the apps, shows they must subscribe even though they’re already within a paid subscription period. They tap subscribe and it says they’ve subscribed. Tap restore and it says their subscription isn’t currently active.
- When tapping to purchase a subscription the correct information appears showing the user is subscribed with the correct expiration date.  However, the actual renewal is not confirmed and the user cannot progress past the purchase screen.
- Free trial subscriptions (production) and sandbox subscriptions are working fine.
- I've had a complaint from production but also seem to be able to reproduce in the TestFlight sandbox as well. From what I can tell, when you repurchase or restore, a new transaction is not being added to the queue and thus there is no receipt to send to the server for verification. At least in my case, the `/verifyReceipt` endpoint appears to be working OK.
- We're experiencing the same issue as well. Lots of users are sending us emails and tickets about the issue. We've changed nothing (our last update was 3 months ago), then yesterday it started malfunctioning.

Comment: Yes we are facing same issue. can you tell me more about your issue? is it fixed by apple or you are still having that issue?

Answer (score 4):

we are having the same issue. It’s been a full day now with no response from Apple but I’ve at least found a workaround that may help your users until Apple fixes this mysterious issue.

1.) tap subscribe/manage/cancel the subscription

2.) return to the app and resubscribe

I’ve sent this to some users as a temporary fix. This isn’t the final answer as only Apple can fix it but this can help users gain access in the mean time.

---

**Edit**: I can't add a separate answer as this issue is still closed, but here is a POSSIBLE (not yet verified by me) fix taken from [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/133367) by asdadsasda:

> I previously had logic like this:

1. Get a list of all IAP receipts from Apple
2. Pick the last one from the list and assume it is the latest
3. Check the expiry date and lock/unlock subscription based on that

> I guess Apple used to return these in order so picking the last one was OK. Now they are returning in a different order. Changed the logic to be like this:

1. Get a list of all IAP receipts from Apple
2. Sort the receipts by expiry date ascending
3. Pick the last one from the list
4. Check the expiry date and lock/unlock subscription based on that

> After pushing out this change, I had confirmation from two of my complaining customers that they were able to unlock their subscription.

Comment: Thank you! That is the solution we went with as well and it did fix it. Classic apple changing something without telling people. I appreciate your response and hope you have resolved the issue on your end.